Idiomatic SwiftUI, a combination picker and presenter
I am learning Swift & SwiftUI after 15 years doing VBScript & PowerShell. My current learning project is Stewart Lynch's BookList based on SwiftData. And as part of that project he has a View to show & set the book rating, with the code to just show a static presentation done in the BookListView.
As an extra exercise I reworked his "picker" to allow it to also be used to show a static presentation of the current rating, which is working as I wanted. But now I want to get some feedback on that effort. Is it "idiomatic" SwiftUI, or is there a better way to approach the problem? Would two different views where each is a simple as it can be for it's single purpose be better? Or is this within a generally accepted range of "related purposes"?
I know this opens the whole "opinion" can of worms, but I am actually hoping to get a diversity of opinion with some technical reasoning behind those opinions, because I think I can learn as much or more from that as I can from doing the code itself.
Also, one thing I am contemplating now is how to deal with error conditions. If none of the three optionals is provided I will probably return an empty view, and if the mutable optional or the max optional is provided without the counterpart I will probably throw an error. Likely also if I have the max provided with the current optional.
But this is where I started to question how idiomatic this is, because in PowerShell you can do a parameter set, and any mix of parameters that doesn't meet any defined parameter set throws automatically. Since Swift doesn't (to my knowledge) offer that option, I have to do all that error checking myself, which makes me think two views with no mutually exclusive optionals may be the more idiomatic approach.
But I think the entire process has been valuable, because I learned a lot about manual Inits and also how optionals work, and if it turns out I also detected a bit of a code smell in my approach here, well that's super valuable too.
// https://gist.github.com/StewartLynch/03372c873fef568e0a613a968adbae69

import SwiftUI

public struct RatingView: View {
    let currentRating: Int?
    let maxRating: Int?
    @Binding var mutableRating: Int?
    let width:Int
    let color: UIColor
    let sfSymbol: String
    
    public init(
        currentRating: Int? = nil,
        maxRating: Int? = nil,
        mutableRating: Binding<Int?> = Binding.constant(nil),
        width: Int = 20,
        color: UIColor = .systemYellow,
        sfSymbol: String = "star"
    ) {
        self.currentRating = currentRating
        self.maxRating = maxRating
        self._mutableRating = mutableRating
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.sfSymbol = sfSymbol
    }

    public var body: some View {
        if maxRating == nil {
            if currentRating != nil {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<currentRating!, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Image(systemName: sfSymbol)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .fillImage(true)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(color))
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: CGFloat(currentRating! * width))
            }
        } else {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: sfSymbol)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .symbolVariant(.slash)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(color))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation{
                            mutableRating = nil
                        }
                    }
                    .opacity(mutableRating == 0 ? 0 : 1)
          
                ForEach(0..<maxRating!, id: \.self) { rating in
                    Image(systemName: sfSymbol)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .fillImage(correctImage(for: rating))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color(color))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation{
                                mutableRating = rating + 1
                            }
                        }
                }
            }.frame(width: CGFloat(maxRating! * width))
        }
    }
    
    func correctImage(for rating: Int) -> Bool {
        if let mutableRating, rating < mutableRating {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct FillImage: ViewModifier {
    let fill: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if fill {
            content
                .symbolVariant(.fill)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func fillImage(_ fill: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(FillImage(fill: fill))
    }
}

#Preview ("mutating") {
    struct PreviewWrapper: View {
        @State var currentRating: Int? = 2
        
        var body: some View {
            RatingView(
                maxRating: 5,
                mutableRating: $currentRating,
                width: 30,
                color: .red,
                sfSymbol: "heart"
            )
        }
    }
    return PreviewWrapper()
}

#Preview ("non mutating") {
    struct PreviewWrapper: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            RatingView(
                currentRating: 3,
                width: 20,
                color: .red,
                sfSymbol: "heart"
            )
        }
    }
    return PreviewWrapper()
}

